# Babel 7 upgrade

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, gulp, babeljs

I have updated babel 6 to babel 7.
this is a part from my package. For some reason my app still looking for "babel-core" module.
i have deleted package-lock.json and node modules and install them again, I did npm rebuild --force. No luck, any suggestions ?

```
"@babel/core": "^7.6.2",
"@babel/cli": "^7.6.2",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.5.5",
"@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.6.2",
"@babel/polyfill": "^7.6.0",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.6.2",
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
"@babel/runtime": "^7.6.2",
"@devexpress/dx-core": "^1.10.3",
"@devexpress/dx-grid-core": "^1.10.3",
"@devexpress/dx-react-core": "^1.10.3",
"@devexpress/dx-react-grid": "^1.10.3",
"@devexpress/dx-react-grid-material-ui": "^1.10.0",
"@material-ui/core": "^3.9.3",
"@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.2",
"babel-eslint": "^8.2.1",
"babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
"babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.2.1",
"babel-plugin-transform-dev-warning": "^0.1.1",
"babel-plugin-transform-regenerator": "^6.26.0",
```

ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module 'babel-core'
Require stack:
- /Users/hakob/Documents/Projects/dashboard/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
- /Users/hakob/Documents/Projects/dashboard/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js
- /Users/hakob/Documents/Projects/dashboard/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js
- /Users/hakob/Documents/Projects/dashboard/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js
- /Users/hakob/Documents/Projects/dashboard/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js
- /Users/hakob/Documents/Projects/dashboard/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js
- /Users/hakob/Documents/Projects/dashboard/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js
- /Users/hakob/Documents/Projects/dashboard/gulpfile.babel.js
- /Users/hakob/Documents/Projects/dashboard/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/gulp-cli/lib/versioned/^4.0.0/index.js
- /Users/hakob/Documents/Projects/dashboard/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/gulp-cli/index.js
- /Users/hakob/Documents/Projects/dashboard/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:780:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:685:27)

Comment: update babel loader to 8?

Comment: Indeed it's to do with `babel-loader` still being at `v7` when it should be at `v8`. Check out how I upgraded it here in my package on GitHub https://github.com/techouse/es6-boilerplate/commit/db35b769cec96b320bab9521ef8f2555c2a1183d#diff-b9cfc7f2cdf78a7f4b91a753d10865a2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The babel loader 7 requires babel-core, you should update babel loader to 8 like @Chris Li said.

Comment: I did loader update to v8, and now I have this error:
Module build failed: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed: Error: Missing binding /Users/hakob/Documents/Projects/dashboard/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-72/binding.node
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: OS X 64-bit with Node.js 12.x

Found bindings for the following environments:
  - OS X 64-bit with Node.js 6.x

Comment: https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2536#issuecomment-525610740

Comment: loader to 8 fixed the problem, just you need to run  npm rebuild --force. At least in my case after  npm rebuild --force it is working. thanks